# Converting a python project into an .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

My python project has many .mp3 , .mp4 and many other folders. If i use pyinstaller to convert it into an .exe file, will the above mentioned files automatically compile into the exe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller adding data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files)

Answer (score 0):

I have used pyinstaller for the same purpose, so yes it will convert it into executable. Have a look at this question [Convert python file that contains mp3 song into executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454861/convert-python-file-that-contains-mp3-song-into-executable). It will save you some time.

If you have many mp3 and mp4 files they must be in the same folder that you are trying to convert to exe. Also, you can use the —onedir option to create  one-folder bundle containing the executable.

Comment: Happy to hear that. If my answer has helped you find the solution you can accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Currently i dont have that much reputation